# Firestore @DocumentId does not create a field in the document (Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase SDK in an Android application in Java, and I want to store the ID of the document inside the document. For example, let's say I have a class called Student and I want to store the roll number of the student as the document Id as well as in the field rollNum; I dont want the roll number to be generated randomly, I want to input a roll number, but by following the below code I am unable to do so.

```
class Student {
        @DocumentId private String rollNum;
        private String name;
        private String surname;

        public String getRollNum() {
            return rollNum;
        }

        public void setRollNum(String rollNum) {
            this.rollNum = rollNum;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }

        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }
    }
```

And I am creating a Document using the following code

```
        Student data = new Student();
        data.setName("Test");
        data.setSurname("Test");
        data.setRollNum("9999999");
        db.collection("TestCollection").document("9999999").set(data);
```

Even calling the `data.setRollNum("9999999")` does not set the field on Firestore. What should be done in this case? I know that a workaround would be removing `@DocumentId`. Is there any other solution available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@DocumentId` does not store the value in the firestore document, but while converting to object using `documentSnapshot.toObject(Student.class)` the field `student.rollNum` will be populated.